# How to limit client access defined in OAuth2 settings?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

In a REST API developed with Sping Boot and OAuth2 is it possible to limit user access according to client defined in the Authorization Server settings?

For example, in the Authorization Server I have the following client configuration:

```
clients.inMemory()
            .withClient(uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getClientId())
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getSecret()))
            .scopes("openid")
            .authorities("ROLE_TESTE")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit","refresh_token", "password", "authorization_code")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValidity)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValidity)
```

And in the security configuration part of Spring in HttpSecurity I have the following configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .csrf() 
    .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
.and()
    .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
    .headers()
    .frameOptions()
    .disable()
.and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
.and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);
}
```

How can I limit an OAuth client with authorities "ROLE_TESTE" to not access the api addresses set only for ADMIN?

**Edited ...**

I edited the codes to look like this:

UAA / OAuth2:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class UaaConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
    /**
     * Access tokens will not expire any earlier than this.
     */
    private static final int MIN_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECS = 60;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @EnableResourceServer
    public static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private final TokenStore tokenStore;

        private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

        private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

        public ResourceServerConfiguration(TokenStore tokenStore, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties, CorsFilter corsFilter) {
            this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
            this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
            this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
//                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/api/**").access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_TESTE')")
                ;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId("jhipster-uaa").tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }
    }

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    private final UaaProperties uaaProperties;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UaaConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties, UaaProperties uaaProperties, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
        this.uaaProperties = uaaProperties;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        int accessTokenValidity = uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getAccessTokenValidityInSeconds();
        accessTokenValidity = Math.max(accessTokenValidity, MIN_ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECS);
        int refreshTokenValidity = uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getRefreshTokenValidityInSecondsForRememberMe();
        refreshTokenValidity = Math.max(refreshTokenValidity, accessTokenValidity);
        /*
        For a better client design, this should be done by a ClientDetailsService (similar to UserDetailsService).
         */
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient(uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getClientId())
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(uaaProperties.getWebClientConfiguration().getSecret()))
            .scopes("openid")
            .authorities("ROLE_TESTE")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit","refresh_token", "password", "authorization_code")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValidity)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValidity)
            .and()
            .withClient(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getClientAuthorization().getClientId())
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getClientAuthorization().getClientSecret()))
            .scopes("web-app")
            .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds((int) jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getTokenValidityInSeconds())
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds((int) jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getJwt().getTokenValidityInSecondsForRememberMe());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        //pick up all  TokenEnhancers incl. those defined in the application
        //this avoids changes to this class if an application wants to add its own to the chain
        Collection<TokenEnhancer> tokenEnhancers = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(TokenEnhancer.class).values();
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(new ArrayList<>(tokenEnhancers));
        endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false);             //don't reuse or we will run into session inactivity timeouts
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    /**
     * Apply the token converter (and enhancer) for token store.
     * @return the JwtTokenStore managing the tokens.
     */
    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    /**
     * This bean generates an token enhancer, which manages the exchange between JWT acces tokens and Authentication
     * in both directions.
     *
     * @return an access token converter configured with the authorization server's public/private keys
     */
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
             new ClassPathResource(uaaProperties.getKeyStore().getName()), uaaProperties.getKeyStore().getPassword().toCharArray())
             .getKeyPair(uaaProperties.getKeyStore().getAlias());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
                "isAuthenticated()");
    }
}
```

Gateway:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final OAuth2Properties oAuth2Properties;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    public SecurityConfiguration(OAuth2Properties oAuth2Properties, CorsFilter corsFilter) {
        this.oAuth2Properties = oAuth2Properties;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf() //.disable()
            .ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
//            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter) {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter(OAuth2SignatureVerifierClient signatureVerifierClient) {
        return new OAuth2JwtAccessTokenConverter(oAuth2Properties, signatureVerifierClient);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("loadBalancedRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate loadBalancedRestTemplate(RestTemplateCustomizer customizer) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        customizer.customize(restTemplate);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("vanillaRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate vanillaRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Attempting to log in appears this error in the UAA console:

`2019-06-07 16:04:59.727 DEBUG 32186 --- [  XNIO-2 task-7] c.t.uaa.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Enter: com.testando.uaa.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-06-07T19:04:59.727Z, principal=admin, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=remoteAddress=172.17.1.155, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]`

Answer (score 2):

In your resource server configuration you could use Spring Security's expression-based access control with `#oauth2.clientHasRole`, see [`OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods#clientHasRole`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/expression/OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.html#clientHasRole(java.lang.String)):

> Check if the OAuth2 client (not the user) has the role specified. To check the user's roles see #hasRole(String).

See also: [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html):

> **Configuring An OAuth-Aware Expression Handler**
>
> You may want to take advantage of Spring Security's expression-based access control. An expression handler will be registered by default in the `@EnableResourceServer` setup. The expressions include *#oauth2.clientHasRole*, *#oauth2.clientHasAnyRole*, and *#oath2.denyClient* which can be used to provide access based on the role of the oauth client (see `OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods` for a comprehensive list).

Comment: @user2831852: You added ` .antMatchers("/api/**").access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_TESTE')")` and so only client with role `ROLE_TESTE` could access `/api/**`. Do you want this?

Comment: @user2831852 I asked, because in your question you wrote:* "ROLE_TESTE" to not access the api addresses* You did the opposite.

Comment: @user2831852 I don't know JHipster. What is the Gateway configuration? Which is your resource configuration? Could you add the full classes, so I could see the inheritance?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! In this case, when attempting to log into the system, OAuth fails to apply the rule, ie it fails by allowing or denying access to ROLE_TESTE. I'll add the classes in the question so you can take a look. Thank you.

Comment: I changed the code in the question by adding the complete classes and the error, I do not have a resource code because the test failed to login and I had no way to test access to the resources. The code is from the gateway and UAA. I also added the code in GitHub if you want to test ([link](https://github.com/AndreKrebs/microservice-test)) and if you want to look at this [link of JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-uaa/) there is information about the structure that I am using in the test.